Could you help me with a proof of a property of fibonacci and lucas numbers using induction?
The property is as defined as
$a_{2n}= a_n b_n$. Where $a_n$ is the fibonacci sequence and $b_n$ is the sequence of lucas numbers.
Fibonacci series is $a_1 = a_2 =1,a_3 = 2,a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ and lucas numbers are $b_1 = 1, b_n = b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$ and $b_n= a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}$ for $n$ more than or equal to $2$.
You have to prove it using induction or strong induction.I have reached 'till say $a_{2n} a_n b_n$ then for $n+1$
\begin{align*}
a_{2(n+1) }& =a_{2n +2} \\
& =b_{2n+1} - a_{2n} \\
& = b_{2n+1} - a_n b_n
\end{align*}
Now I am stuck.

This question is similar to: Fibonacci / Lucas Numbers Relationship: $F_{2n} = F_n L_n$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. There are also quite a few fairly closely related results, ...

(cont.) e.g., Lucas sequence equivalent for the tribonacci sequence?, Prove that for the Fibonacci sequence $(F_n)$, $F_n$ divides $F_{2n}$., Mathematical induction on Lucas sequence and Fibonacci sequence, fibonacci and lucas numbers induction, etc. Finally, welcome to Math SE.
